# Not able to sort a list properly in ocaml

Tags: sorting, ocaml

So I'm trying to sort this list of integers so that all the even numbers are in the front and the odds are all in the back. I have my program now which works for the most part but it keeps reversing the order of my odds numbers which I don't want it to do. E.g. given the input [1;2;3;4;5;6] I would like to get [2;4;6;1;3;5], but I'm getting [2;4;6;5;3;1] Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
let rec evens (xl:int list) (odd:int list) : int list =
   match xl with
      | [] -> []
      | h::t ->
         if h mod 2 = 0
            then (h)::evens t odd
         else
            evens t odd@[(h)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The main part of your current code parses like this:

```
if h mod 2 = 0 then
    h :: (evens t odd)
else
    (evens t odd) @ [h]
```

It says this: if the next number `h` is even, sort out the rest of the list, then add `h` to the front. If the next number `h` is odd, sort out the rest of the list, then add `h` to the end. So it follows that the odd numbers will be reversed at the end.

It's worth noting that your parameter named `odd` is always passed along unchanged, and hence will always be an empty list (or whatever you pass as the second parameter of `evens`).

When I first looked at your code, I assumed you were planning to accumulate the odd numbers in the `odd` parameter. If you want to do that, you need to make two changes. First you need to rewrite like this:

```
if h mod 2 = 0 then
    h :: evens t odd
else
    evens t (odd @ [h])
```

The precedence rules of OCaml require the parentheses if you want to add `h` to the `odd` parameter. Your current code adds `h` to the returned result of `evens` (as above).

This rewrite will accumulate the odd numbers, in order, in the `odd` parameter.

Then you need to actually use the odd parameter at the end of the recursion. I.e., you need to use it when `xl` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library has a neat solution to your problem.

```
List.partition (fun x -> x mod 2 = 0) [1;2;3;4;5;6]
- : int list * int list = ([2; 4; 6], [1; 3; 5])
```

The `partition` function splits your list into a tuple of two lists:

1. The list of elements that validate a predicate;
2. The list of elements that don't.

All you have to do is combine those lists together.

```
let even_first l =
  let evens, odds = List.partition (fun x -> x mod 2 = 0) l in
  evens @ odds
```

---

If you want to make it more generic, let the predicate be an argument:

```
let order_by_predicate ~f l =
  let valid, invalid = List.partition f l in
  valid @ invalid
```